# Xpath or For-each to use to fetch particular node value based on condition

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<Endorsements>
  <Endorsement>
    <VehicleNumber>1</VehicleNumber>
      <Vehicle>
        <Year>2014</Year>
        <Make>Honda</Make>
        <Model>CAB</Model>
      </Vehicle>
   </Endorsement>                
   <Endorsement>                 
      <VehicleNumber>0</VehicleNumber>
      <Vehicle>
        <Year>2014</Year>
        <Make>Activa</Make>
        <Model>SUV</Model>
      </Vehicle>
    </Endorsement>
    <Endorsement>
      <VehicleNumber>0</VehicleNumber>
      <Vehicle>
        <Year>2014</Year>               
        <Make>Suzuki</Make>
        <Model>Sedan</Model>
      </Vehicle>
   </Endorsement>
 </Endorsements>
```

I need to fetch the value of year whose Make is "Suzuki" and whose VehicleNumber is 1. Is it good to loop through `<xsl:for-each>` or use `contains[text (),'']` xpath?

I have tried with XPath, but it's not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "*Tried with xpath, its not working?*" Why don't you post your attempt? Note that your input has no entry that meets the criteria. In any case, there's no need to loop - you can select the nodes you want directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Endorsement[VehicleNumber=1]/Vehicle[Make="Suzuki"]/Year
```

Tested here:
http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

Basic XPath Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp